# capturing shell script response code in python script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

Here's my python script

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.Popen('./test.sh', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, err = result.communicate()
print output
```

Here's my shell script

```
testFn(){
exit 1;
}

testFn "hello"
```

I need to print 1 after executing the python script but I see nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`output` comes from stdout. You want the return code.

Get that by:

```
result.returncode
```

Comment: It is not impossible that he wants the script to `echo 1` and capture its output, but that's obscure and unidiomatic.  This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I got it now. I removed communicate but realized that's required to complete the process.